# starting geth node with db facility

Tags: go-ethereum, rpc

I'm trying to start geth node to perform queries about blockchain state.

The command that worked for me year ago as follows:

```
geth --rpc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3" --rpcaddr "localhost" --rpcport "8545"
```

However `geth` node refuses to init one of namespaces like this:

```
ERROR[08-15|15:50:04.923] Unavailable modules in HTTP API list     unavailable=[db] available="[admin debug web3 eth txpool personal ethash miner net]"
```

I'd be ok without it, however [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs) doc clearly says that `db` namespace is needed to make use of `getBalance` which is essential part of targeted thing.

My geth version is `1.9.19-stable-3e064192` & windows if that matters.

What should I try further to get this going or maybe `db` namespace is no longer required for balance queries?

Answer (score 1):

If with the js console, you should use `eth.getBalance(...)`.

If with a rpc request, you should use this body

```
{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "id":1,
    "method":"eth_getBalance",
    "params":["..."]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/20773#issuecomment-619764495][1]

I come across the similer problem.
I found a suggestion, you may check out form the link above,but I have not try it out

appoint command `--rpcapi="web3,eth,net,db,personal"`

my problem as below

`ERROR[03-29|08:41:48.709] Unavailable modules in HTTP API list     unavailable="[db network]" available="[admin debug web3 eth txpool personal ethash miner net]"`

in which it said that the `network` is also a unavailable module

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).